# How to capture back arrow button in webview app using plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webview

I want to add an event when user clicks on the back arrow button in webview using but I couldn't able to find any particular article. I am not using react native, just want to do using plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use HTML 5 popstate() function.  For example:

```
window.onpopstate = func;

function func() {
   //do your stuff here
}
```

You can also use an anonymous function as such:

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
   //do stuff here
}
```

However, when you say webview, are you talking about JavaFX webview, as in, something external from the normal html/css/js?  If so, I would assum this popstate should still work.

Comment: I am not sure what is JavaFX webview, what I am doing is rendering microsite inside Android/iOS app using webview. I have added a background audio file which is not getting stop/pause when user clicks on back arrow button in android. So I want to make it stop when user comes out of my webview.

Comment: Ok, so that's similar to what I was thinking of.  Have you tried my proposed solution yet?  If so, how has it worked?

Comment: I tried but no luck, I had to take help from backend team :)

Comment: It might be different on Android/iOS app (which you might want to mention in the body of the question in the future), but I take it the event did not fire at all, correct?